# how to print a column with a delimiter in csvsimple

Tags: tables, delimiters, csvsimple

I'm using `csvsimple` for my tables. One of the columns contains data such as "(73,1)". Since it's quoted, it is proper csv. How can I configure csvsimple to treat this data as part of one column and not split at the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csvsimple` has no direct support for grouping with `"`. Grouping can be done with TeX curly brackets like `{(73,1)}`.

I think, your choices are:

- Change the grouping from `"(73,1)"` to `{(73,1)}`. If you produce the data manually, this is the easiest way. If the data is produced as output of an automated process, you may not have that choice (easily).
- Use [CSV-Sorter](http://t-f-s.github.io/csvsorter/) to filter your csv file during compilation to a suitable format. CSV-Sorter is supported by `csvsimple` and needs a Java runtime on your system. Once set up, you can use `"` in your data files and filtering is done on-the-fly.
- Replace `cvsimple` by `datatool`. `datatool` allows to use `"` directly as far as I know.

The main purpose of `csvsimple` is to provide lightweight support for csv files. Sorting and special data conversion is not supported directly, but given to an external tool (CSV-Sorter). `datatool` has a different philosophy and provides much more features directly through LaTeX.

Comment: I have changed the output of the file from `.csv` to `.tsv`. Then I configured `csvsimple` to use `separator=tab`. This way I was able to use the formatting I already had.